# Invoke diffrent Functions in Option tag

Tags: javascript, html, function, tags

I have 3 options in a Select tag. And when I select them I need to invoke 3 different functions. How do I do it?

```
`     <select>
            <option selected disabled="">Sort</option>
            <option>Ascending</option>
            <option>Descending</option>
            <option>Basic JSON</option>     
      </select>`
```

3 Function Names: sortArrAcc() , sortArrDec(),  load()

So If I select Ascending then It should Invoke sort Arra cc() and So on. **Without JQuery.**

Comment: You can have a single function for "onchange" event for select. Within that function make the control go to your respective functions based on the value given to the option tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:
Consider you've the following dropdown:

```
            <select name="mselect" id="mselect">
                <option  value="">Select</option>
                <option value="1">Ascending</option>
                <option value="2">Descending</option>
                <option value="3">Basic JSON</option>
         </select>
```

And Here is the javascript:

```
        var sortArrAcc = function () {
            // invoke sort array cc and do your necessary work 
            console.log('sortArrAcc');
        };
        var sortArrDec = function () {
            // invoke sort array cc and do your necessary work 
            console.log('sortArrDec');
        };
        var load = function () {
            // do your necessary work 
            console.log('load');
        };

       var funcArray = [sortArrAcc, sortArrDec, load];

        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            document.getElementById('mselect').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
                var elem = e.target;
                var selectedOption = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex];
                if (selectedOption.value && funcArray[+selectedOption.value]) {
                    funcArray[+selectedOption.value]();
                }
            });
         });
```